# systemd-nspawn vs chroot and bind mount?

Tags: systemd, chroot, systemd-nspawn

Does `systemd-nspawn` do special inside to a `chroot` or does it just provide a different method of running `chroot` + the appropriate ro `--bind` mounts for `proc`, `sys`. The [docs say,](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-nspawn.html)

> similar to chroot(1), but more powerful since it fully virtualizes the file system hierarchy, as well as the process tree, the various IPC subsystems and the host and domain name

I'm not sure of how any of those are defined,

- virtualizes the file system hierarchy

  Isn't this what `chroot` does changing the root?
- as well as the process tree

  I'm not sure what this means.
- various IPC subsystems

  What subsystems? Can someone tell me exactly what that means?
- host and domain name

  I'm not sure what this means either? Isn't this just `/proc/sys/kernel/domainname`, and `/proc/sys/kernel/hostname`

I've used `chroot` and `mount --bind` scripts. It seems like this is more convince but I'm blurry on any additional functionality. What new things does this provide to me?

Comment: `systemd-nspawn` can do almost the equivalent of a full boot (the init system is started, services are started according to the init config, etc.). They're pretty much containers. chroot + bind mounts are not anywhere close to being fully functional containers.

Answer (score 5):

- virtualizes the file system hierarchy

It uses mount namespaces. It's more powerful than `chroot` because you can mount and umount filesystems under your namespace and those will be hidden from the outside, or from other mount namespaces.

Take a look at [this article](https://lwn.net/Articles/531114/) on Linux namespaces (and, in particular, mount namespaces) to have an overview of what they do.

- as well as the process tree

That means you get new PID numbers inside the namespace. PID 1 inside the namespace could be PID 12001 outside it, PID 40 inside it might be PID 13987 outside it, and so on. In particular, not all PIDs are mapped inside the namespace, so if you use a command such as `ps -ef` inside it, you'll only see processes that are in that namespace, and not ones from the outside, or from other pid namespaces.

The article mentioned above also gives a nice overview on PID namespaces.

- various IPC subsystems

Shared memory, semaphores... The stuff shown by the `ipcs` command. Again, that article I pointed out has a bit more on that. (If you haven't heard of SysV IPC or the `ipcs` command, you can probably ignore this one.)

- host and domain name

This is actually the UTS namespace, and once again, that article has more details.

It virtualizes what the `uname` command returns (you can take a look at `uname -a` inside the container.) Also, `hostname` and `domainname` commands. Yes, the two `/proc` files you mentioned too.

So, in short, this is telling you that `systemd-nspawn` is using Linux namespaces to give you container isolation. That's also what other container technologies (such as Docker) employ.

Answer (score -1):

There is also an important limitation of systemd-nspawn: you can only have one instance at any one time, while chroot allows you to chroot multiple times into the same directory.

That means that if you use systemd-nspawn to "chroot" into a directory, you cannot run it again from e.g. another shell until the first instance exits.